# Como identificar o tipo da variavel em C?

Tags: c, variáveis

Em linguagens como *Nodejs*, *Ruby*, *Lua*, etc. Quando quero saber qual é o tipo da minha variável basta usar a função `typeof` (não necessariamente nas linguagens citadas) que retorna uma *String* com o nome do tipo da minha variável.

Mas como fazer isso em C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linguagem *C*, não possui uma macro capaz de fazer isso, mas a partir do `gcc5` tem a implementação do `_Generic`, que é capaz de emitir um retorno a partir de um tipo de variável.

```
#define typeof(var) _Generic( (var),\
char: "Char",\
int: "Integer",\
float: "Float",\
char *: "String",\
void *: "Pointer",\
default: "Undefined")

int main(){
    int x = 6;
    void *p = NULL;
    char *s = "text";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", typeof(x), typeof(p), typeof(s));
}
```

Saida:

```
>Integer
>Pointer
>String
```

Referencia: [**cpp-reference generic**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)